# How can we generate multiple output file in benthos?

Tags: etl, pipeline, data-pipeline, benthos

Input Data:

```
{ "name": "Coffee", "price": "$1.00" } 
{ "name": "Tea", "price": "$2.00" } 
{ "name": "Coke", "price": "$3.00" } 
{ "name": "Water", "price": "$4.00" }
```

extension.yaml

```yaml
input:
  label: ""
  file:
    paths: [./input/*]
    codec: lines
    max_buffer: 1000000
    delete_on_finish: false
pipeline:
  processors:  
    - bloblang: |
        root.name = this.name.uppercase()
        root.price = this.price
output:
  file:
    path: "result/file1.log"
    codec: lines
```

I want to create an output file based on the input and defined processor for our need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extension.yaml

```yaml
input:
  label: ""
  file:
    paths: [./input/*]
    codec: lines
    max_buffer: 1000000
    delete_on_finish: false
pipeline:
  processors:  
    - bloblang: |
        root.name = this.name.uppercase()
        root.price = this.price
output:
  broker:
    pattern: fan_out
    outputs:
    - file:
        path: "result/file1.log"
        codec: lines
    - file:
        path: "result/file2.log"
        codec: lines
      processors:
        - bloblang: |
            root.name = this.name.lowercase()
```

It will generate two output files "file1.log" & file2.log".

file1.log

```
{"name":"COFFEE","price":"$1.00"}
{"name":"TEA","price":"$2.00"}
{"name":"COKE","price":"$3.00"}
{"name":"WATER","price":"$4.00"}
```

file2.log

```
{"name":"coffee"}
{"name":"tea"}
{"name":"coke"}
{"name":"water"}
```

Here we can use something called 'Broker' in Benthos as shown in the above example.

It allows you to route messages to multiple child outputs using a range of brokering patterns.

You can refer to this link for more information: [Broker](https://www.benthos.dev/docs/components/outputs/broker)